# Why does Oracle use MINUS instead of EXCEPT?

Tags: terminology

I just [saw this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) after seeing [`MINUS` in this powerpoint](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kiss/09ab2/semijoins.ppt) and looking for more information.

> `MINUS` Example The following statement combines results with the `MINUS` operator, which returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second:
>
> ```
> SELECT product_id FROM inventories
> MINUS
> SELECT product_id FROM order_items;
> ```

I'm just curious what's the historic reason for using `MINUS` instead of `EXCEPT`?  Does anyone else use `MINUS`? I assume this predates the SQL Spec?

Comment: It probably stems from set theory.  A database is just a set and the select is a subset.  Some languages use a minus sign to remove one subset from another.

Comment: `EXCEPT` was added in SQL-92, I suspect `MINUS` predates that (Oracle 7 had it, I can’t remember for sure but I think Oracle 6 might have had it too). I don’t have sources to hand to back that up though.